# How can I configure DNS and domain without a control panel? 

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain

I have registered a domain at a domain provider, and now I am renting a CentOS dedicated server at GoDaddy.  I did not choose a panel when I bought the server, but I don't know how to configure the domain information on it via ssh - without the control panel.

Their help suggests that I buy "Parallels Plesk Panel", but I don't want to buy a panel which will just allow me to set the domain.

Comment: I understand that English is probably your second language, but I don't understand what you are asking for when you say **And now how to get DNS and configure domain with SSH?**  Are you asking about how to setup DNS records, how to configure a web server or something else?

Comment: @Zoredache, Yes, My main language is not English. So, my situation is: I want set a domain to my server, but my hand just have Putty with SSH commond. So how can I get the DNS from `Godaddy`? then set the DNS to my domain provider, and set www.mydomain to `Godaddy` server? I have already get a IP address from GODADDY, but never a DNS. This is my first play DNS and domain. So thanks for a great teach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like BIND is installed on all variants? If that's the case all you need to do is login and configure it and there's plenty of information out there on BIND configuration,
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialWebSiteConfig.html#DNS
http://www.howtoforge.com/howtos/dns/bind
All you need to do is substitute your 'settings' for what's in this documentation.

Comment: thanks for some links to reference. May be I would cost more time to read and learn it.

Answer (score 2):

When you registered your domain with some domain provider (aka registrar), you were likely asked to provide the nameservers or DNS Servers that answer for your domain.  These would also be called the Authoritative nameservers.  I'd guess that it's either that domain provider or else it's GoDaddy.

Whoever owns/runs those nameservers is who you will have to give the IP address that GoDaddy gave to you along with the hostname you wish to use; such as www.yourdomain.com.  They will configure it in the servers so that www.yourdomain.com resolves to your new GoDaddy IP.

If you are already able to SSH into your Linux host (or if you have another *nix host), run this from a command prompt: 
`dig mydomain.com` (or whatever the ending is).
You will see a section called the ANSWER section, you should see "SOA" and after that will be the nameserver(s) who are Authoritative for your domain.

Alternatively, you can go to GoDaddy's front page, click in the Search box, and in the dropdown select the "Whois search" and type in your domain name.  In the resulting page, scroll down to where it says "Domain servers in listed order:" and it will list the Authoritative nameservers for you, which should help indicate who is managing DNS for your domain.